# composer not found Swagger class for get api in php file

Tags: php, composer-php, swagger

I had to use the `Swagger-php` package to use an `api` and I installed this package in the `composer` service and it was included in the `composer.json` file, but when using the methods This package gives me an `class ... not found` error, the first time I encounter this problem and I could not find a useful answer through Google search.

Note: I installed this package in the same way as the previous packages and all packages respond to each other (`composer require [package name]`)

- The contents of the `composer.json` file

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.2",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.0",
        "zircote/swagger-php": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.11",
        "sendinblue/api-v3-sdk": "7.x.x"
   }
```

- The contents of the file `autoload_real.php`

```
<?php
class ComposerAutoloaderInit9a732474ebcdab3ca8b0d72c7250c12c
{
    private static $loader;

    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
     */
    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }

        require __DIR__ . '/platform_check.php';

        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit9a732474ebcdab3ca8b0d72c7250c12c', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit9a732474ebcdab3ca8b0d72c7250c12c', 'loadClassLoader'));

        $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

            call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit9a732474ebcdab3ca8b0d72c7250c12c::getInitializer($loader));
        } else {
            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->set($namespace, $path);
            }

            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
            }

            $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
            if ($classMap) {
                $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
            }
        }

        $loader->register(true);

        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            $includeFiles = Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit9a732474ebcdab3ca8b0d72c7250c12c::$files;
        } else {
            $includeFiles = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_files.php';
        }
        foreach ($includeFiles as $fileIdentifier => $file) {
            composerRequire9a732474ebcdab3ca8b0d72c7250c12c($fileIdentifier, $file);
        }

        return $loader;
    }
}
function composerRequire9a732474ebcdab3ca8b0d72c7250c12c($fileIdentifier, $file)
{
    if (empty($GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier])) {
        require $file;

        $GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier] = true;
    }
}
```

- Error text:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Swagger\Client\Configuration" not found ...
```

- Things I did:

1 - I update composer

2 - I insert package repository to composer.json

```
,"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
```

3 - `composer dumpautoload` and `composer run`

- idont change `psr4`,because I did not know how to do it

my code:

```
<?php
require_once("/home/milad/vendor/autoload.php");

// Configure API key authorization: apieco-key
Swagger\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('7UHoMOuKT0bgYv0FmG9xFi70d11DVP0C', 'YOUR_API_KEY');
// Uncomment below to setup prefix (e.g. Bearer) for API key, if needed
// Swagger\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKeyPrefix('apieco-key', 'Bearer');

$api_instance = new Swagger\Client\Api\ConditionsApi();
$apiecoKey = "7UHoMOuKT0bgYv0FmG9xFi70d11DVP0C"; // String | 
$age = "40"; // String | age
$enableTriage5 = true; // Boolean | enable 5-level triage values

try {
    $result = $api_instance->conditions($apiecoKey, $age, $enableTriage5);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling ConditionsApi->conditions: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message and your attempts to resolve that error

Comment: I have added the details you requested

Comment: Please share more details, like the **full and exact error message** and code to reproduce it. What do you mean by "when using the classes"?

Comment: i'm sorry my mean by classes is the methods:

$api_instance = new Swagger\Client\Api\ConditionsApi();

Comment: What have you tried to check **why** this happens? Did you verify that such a class exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `composer.json`, you are using `zircote/swagger-php` in v3. The code you are using looks like something that is not compatible with v3, as the maintainers changed their namespace from `Swagger` to `OpenApi`

You either need to follow a tutorial that is made for v3, or downgrade the package you are using to v2